# Multitenant stream analytics with event hub on Azure

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub, azure-stream-analytics

I am looking for Multi tenant solution where multi tenant data is coming from event hub and getting passed to stream analytics for processing. Later I need to display the live tenant stream on power BI. I am confused with this architecture where I segregate the tenant data when it comes from Event Hub.

One solution I can think of, is to create each tenant table before data comes in Event Hub and then to Stream analytics. But for this I need to know what all tenant we have means pre-config.

I have tried solution for single tenant which work fine but not able to isolate tenant data coming form event hub. May be I am missing something as I am new to Azure.

```
[{"tenantid":"tenant1", "email":"email1@test.com"},
{"tenantid":"tenant1", "email":"email2@test.com"},
{"tenantid":"tenant1", "email":"email3@test.com"}
]
```

Comment: I am interested in this use case too!